# Method not found: 'Void OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.LoadFromDataTable(System.Data.DataTable, Boolean)'

Tags: c#

I have created a DLL that wraps EPPlus(library to generate excels) and it works fine in unit tests and it works fine in other projects.

I have included it in a new project and when I try to use it, I get a `MissingMethodException`:

> Method not found: 'Void
>   OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.LoadFromDataTable(System.Data.DataTable,
>   Boolean)'.

Does anyone have any idea why I might get this error? `LoadFromDataTable` is a method in the library, I have no idea why it can't find it.Both the library and this new project compiled file and I would expect a missing method to be a compile time error, not a run-time error.

Comment: Are the both projects in the same solution and you referenced the library project from your wrapper project or you have deployed your solution to some location and maybe you missing something when deploy.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan They are not part of the same solution but I've used the librry in other solutions before without a problem. 

I am referencing both my wrapper library and the eppplus library that it uses.

Comment: Maybe you have deployed old version of your library?

Comment: Use [fusion log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to find out which exact assembly is loading (maybe from GAC) and you can view the metadata of the loaded assembly to find expected method.